# TypeScript check inferred type against interface

Tags: typescript

**Is there a way to ensure at compile time that an inferred type matches another interface without losing the inferred type?**

Say with have this simple interface and an object which implements it:

```ts
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

const bob = {
  name: "Bob"
}

type Bob = typeof bob;
```

I want to keep the inferred type `Bob` which is more specific than `Person`, but I also want to make sure it matches `Person`.

```
const bob: Bob = {  // this kills the implicit type
  name: "bob"
}

----

const bob = {}  // but I want this to fail, because `name` is missing

----

const bob = {
  name: "Bob",
  age: 30, // I want this to fail too, because it doesn't correspond to `Person`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's fair to say that the "typescript way" would be to extend the interface.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

interface Bob extends Person {
  name: "Bob"
}
```

Admittedly it's not semantically identical, but I think it achieves what you're looking for.

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
}

interface Bob extends Person {
    name: "Bob"
}

function test()
{
    const bob: Bob = {  // works
        name: "Bob"
    }

    const bob2: Bob = {}  // Not allowed

    const bob3: Bob = {
        name: "Bob",
        age: 30, // Not allowed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is managed by a consuming function. For example instead of a no-op that just asserts the type you refactor code that consumes `bob` into functions that accept `Person` type parameters. If you want them to be "More than a Person" you can have a signature like `<T extends Person>(p: T) => void`

That being said it can be done, though it will generate real code that doesn't do anything useful.

Here's an example where an `asserter` function accepts a generic type argument, and produces an object with a `.assert` method that will pass-through the type of whatever you hand it, while also checking it extends the intended type.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

function asserter<Intended>() {
    return {
        assert: function<T>(input: T extends Intended ? T : never): T {
            return input as any
        }
    }
}

// the extra "water" will be accepted, but this won't compile if "name" is missing
const bob = asserter<Person>().assert({ name: '', water: ''})
```